# JavaScript array as function input

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am be beginner in JavaScript, and do not know how to make a simple function with an array/vector as an input. This is the code I have:

```
function semGPA(credits) {
  var c = credits.length;
  return c;
}
```

I want to pass a list of numbers (ex. credits={3,4,5,6}), and have it tell me that there are 4 elements in the variable. So far, I have not found any built in functions that create a working function. Everything I try to use other than +-*/ results in a TypeError. Here it says the property "length" is undefined.

Comment: that is an object, not an array. to actually define an array. use `[]` as `credits = [3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: credits=[3,4,5,6] //this is an array

Comment: you don't need a function for this. Just look at your array's `length` property.

Comment: Can you show us your array variable

Comment: @Wreigh: It's not an object either. It's invalid syntax

Comment: lol yes you're right. @MattBurland

Comment: Thanks for you replies so far. I am trying to write this on Google's Script Editor to write functions to be used in Google Sheets. So, I intend to call the function in Google Sheets using '=semGPA(A1:A5)' for example. I am not sure whether arguments get passed as objects or arrays, or how I would account for either.While I realize this function itself is useless, once I get this figured out, I will be able to write ones where there are multiple arrays as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want. You can pass an array as `credits` and your function will work fine (although it's a bit pointless as is, since you can just directly call `length` on your array):

```
semGPA([1,2,3,4]);    // returns 4
```

Perhaps you meant that you wanted to do something like this?

```
function semGPA() {
  var c = arguments.length;
  return c;
}
```

Which you can call like this:

```
semGPA(1,2,3,4);    // returns 4
```

Which uses the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object which is a special object passed to functions that can be used to access all the arguments (including unnamed arguments) passed to a function.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments the example you have is an Object and not an array.

`var array = [1,2,3,4,5]`

`var object = {1,2,3,4,5} ==> This is not a valid object in Javascript.`

The object notation above expects a key-value pair. something like

`var object = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}`

The `length` property does not exist on an object. However, if you want to check the number of elements in an Object you can make use of the below code which is self explanatory:

```
var credits = {1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4}

function semGPA(credits) {
  var creditKeysArray = Object.keys(credits); //this will give you an array of keys
  var creditLength = c.length;
  return creditLength;
}
```